# How to separate data into morning and afternoon

Tags: r

I have a column "Start time" that has both date and time in it, I would like to separate (and save into different .csv files) all the data that is before noon and after noon.

```
> dput(head(DQ))
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Date = c("2022-02-15", "2022-02-25", 
"2022-02-25", "2022-02-28", "2022-03-01", "2022-03-01"), Start.time = c("2-15-22 11:15:43", 
"2-25-22 8:52:33", "2-25-22 8:55:08", "2-28-22 23:19:36", "3-1-22 8:58:31", 
"3-1-22 21:04:49"), Completion.time = c("2-15-22 11:16:59", "2-25-22 8:55:02", 
"2-25-22 16:16:37", "2-28-22 23:21:52", "3-1-22 9:00:02", "3-1-22 21:06:31"
), Email = c("anonymous", "anonymous", "anonymous", "anonymous", 
"anonymous", "anonymous"), Name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Total.points = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Quiz.feedback = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Participant.Code = c("AE1_04", "AE1_02", 
    "AE1_02", "AE1_02", "AE1_02", "AE1_02"), Points...Participant.Code...Code.du.participant...Code.de.la.participante = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Participant.Code...Code.du.participant...Code.de.la.participante = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Stiffness...Raideur = c(10L, 3L, 2L, 
    6L, 7L, 6L), Points...Stiffness...Raideur = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Stiffness...Raideur = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Fatigue...Fatigue = c(10L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L
    ), Points...Fatigue...Fatigue = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Feedback...Fatigue...Fatigue = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Discomfort...Inconfort = c(7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L), Points...Discomfort...Inconfort = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Discomfort...Inconfort = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Happiness...Joie = c(1L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
    7L, 8L), Points...Happiness...Joie = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), Feedback...Happiness...Joie = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), Productivity...Productivité = c(10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
    8L), Points...Productivity...Productivité = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Productivity...Productivité = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ability.to.concentrate...Capacité.de.se.concentrer = c(7L, 
    8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L), Points...Ability.to.concentrate...Capacité.de.se.concentrer = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Ability.to.concentrate...Capacité.de.se.concentrer = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Alertness...Vigilance = c(7L, 5L, 4L, 
    8L, 6L, 7L), Points...Alertness...Vigilance = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Alertness...Vigilance = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Stress...Stress = c(10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
    7L), Points...Stress...Stress = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Feedback...Stress...Stress = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Back.Pain...Mal.de.dos = c(9L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Points...Back.Pain...Mal.de.dos = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Back.Pain...Mal.de.dos = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Neck.Pain...Douleur.au.cou = c(9L, 4L, 
    3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), Points...Neck.Pain...Douleur.au.cou = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Neck.Pain...Douleur.au.cou = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Head.Pain...Mal.de.tête = c(7L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Points...Head.Pain...Mal.de.tête = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Head.Pain...Mal.de.tête = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Eye.Pain...Douleur.oculaire = c(10L, 
    8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Points...Eye.Pain...Douleur.oculaire = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Eye.Pain...Douleur.oculaire = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.light.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.légère. = c("No / Non", 
    "No / Non", "Yes / Oui", "No / Non", "Yes / Oui", "Yes / Oui"
    ), Points...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.light.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.légère. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.light.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.légère. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c("", 
    "", "brisk 10 min walk", "", "stretching", "Stretching"), 
    Points...If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.moderate.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.modérée. = c("No / Non", 
    "Yes / Oui", "No / Non", "Yes / Oui", "No / Non", "No / Non"
    ), Points...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.moderate.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.modérée. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.moderate.physical.activity...Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.fait.une.activité.physique.modérée. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps.2 = c("", 
    "30 min walk at lunch", "", "Magasiner et un petit strength training et cardio", 
    "", ""), Points...If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps.2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...If.yes..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps.2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.vigorous.physical.activity.....Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.pratiqué.une.activité.physique.intense. = c("No / Non", 
    "No / Non", "No / Non", "No / Non", "No / Non", "No / Non"
    ), Points...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.vigorous.physical.activity.....Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.pratiqué.une.activité.physique.intense. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...In.the.past.24.hours..have.you.done.any.vigorous.physical.activity.....Au.cours.des.dernières.24.heures..avez.vous.pratiqué.une.activité.physique.intense. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), If.so..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), Points...If.so..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...If.so..what.did.you.do.and.for.how.long....Si.oui..qu.avez.vous.fait.et.pendant.combien.de.temps. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Please.add.any.additional.comments.you.have...Veuillez.ajouter.tout.commentaire.supplémentaire.que.vous.avez. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Points...Please.add.any.additional.comments.you.have...Veuillez.ajouter.tout.commentaire.supplémentaire.que.vous.avez. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feedback...Please.add.any.additional.comments.you.have...Veuillez.ajouter.tout.commentaire.supplémentaire.que.vous.avez. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm open to different ways of doing this, either sorting/filtering all of the morning and afternoons OR adding a column that states if it is morning and afternoon OR having it sorted and filtered in R and then having it saved to separate .csv files

please let me know if you need more details

Comment: Have you made any progress yourself? What did you attempt and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What if start time is morning and end time afternoon?

Comment: @Steve I've tried something with excel with no luck, trying to use R in hopes of something I can re use later on when I have a larger data set

Comment: @harre should not be an issue, but no matter, the start time is the main concern

Comment: I'd start by trying to classify a single date-time by morning or afternoon - see [Filter R data frame by hour of the day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57228827/5358968) - then afterwards look at outputting as two csvs.

Comment: @Steve not too sure how to apply this, would you mind showing me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split:

```r
library(dplyr)

DQ <- 
  DQ |>
  mutate(morning = format(as.POSIXct(Start.time, format = "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"), "%H") < 12) |>
  group_by(morning) |>
  group_split()
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 6
     ID Date       Start.time       Completion.time  Email     morning
  <int> <chr>      <chr>            <chr>            <chr>     <lgl>  
1     4 2022-02-28 2-28-22 23:19:36 2-28-22 23:21:52 anonymous FALSE  
2     6 2022-03-01 3-1-22 21:04:49  3-1-22 21:06:31  anonymous FALSE  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID Date       Start.time       Completion.time  Email     morning
  <int> <chr>      <chr>            <chr>            <chr>     <lgl>  
1     1 2022-02-15 2-15-22 11:15:43 2-15-22 11:16:59 anonymous TRUE   
2     2 2022-02-25 2-25-22 8:52:33  2-25-22 8:55:02  anonymous TRUE   
3     3 2022-02-25 2-25-22 8:55:08  2-25-22 16:16:37 anonymous TRUE   
4     5 2022-03-01 3-1-22 8:58:31   3-1-22 9:00:02   anonymous TRUE
```

Then save:

```
library(readr)

write_csv(DQ[[1]], "afternoon.csv")
write_csv(DQ[[2]], "morning.csv")
```

Comment: is there a way to not have a period added between every word in my headers? its affecting some other code

Comment: That's how your data is imported into `R`, so you'll need to check the settings there.

Comment: is there a way to remove that? only for the headers

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152483/avoid-that-space-in-column-name-is-replaced-with-period-when-using-read-cs

Comment: I have this error now ```Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  DQ |>
  mutate(morning = format(as.POSIXct(Start time"```

Comment: Use  these: `` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642116/how-to-use-in-r-to-select-a-column-with-space-in-its-colname

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hms` from the `lubridate` package for this and filter it or create a new column based on your need.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, 
                     Date = c("2022-02-15", "2022-02-25", 
                                  "2022-02-25", "2022-02-28", "2022-03-01", "2022-03-01"), 
                     Start.time = c("2-15-22 11:15:43", "2-25-22 8:52:33", "2-25-22 8:55:08", 
                                    "2-28-22 23:19:36", "3-1-22 8:58:31","3-1-22 21:04:49")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% 
  mutate(time = Start.time %>% str_extract(" .*") %>% str_trim() %>% hms()) %>% 
  mutate(day = ifelse(time >= hms("00:00:00") & time < hms("12:00:00"), "fn", "an"))

  
# A tibble: 6 × 5
ID Date       Start.time       time        day  
<int> <chr>      <chr>            <Period>    <chr>
  1     1 2022-02-15 2-15-22 11:15:43 11H 15M 43S fn   
2     2 2022-02-25 2-25-22 8:52:33  8H 52M 33S  fn   
3     3 2022-02-25 2-25-22 8:55:08  8H 55M 8S   fn   
4     4 2022-02-28 2-28-22 23:19:36 23H 19M 36S an   
5     5 2022-03-01 3-1-22 8:58:31   8H 58M 31S  fn   
6     6 2022-03-01 3-1-22 21:04:49  21H 4M 49S  an
```

Comment: so to do the afternoon count, would I simply change the mutate times from 12:00:01 to 23:59:59 ?

Comment: I have already done the afternoon count as `an` here

Comment: Looking at my file, it does not seem to be separated

Comment: Do you mean your files are not separated, I haven't separated the files here. I created a column with `an` and `fn` data. You can go ahead and subset the data frame into two based on the `day` column.

Comment: oh ok I see, let me try that

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(start_hour = hour(as.POSIXct(Start.time, format = "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")),
         completion_hour = hour(as.POSIXct(Completion.time, format = "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"))) %>%
  mutate(part_of_day = ifelse(start_hour < 12, "morning", "afternoon"))
```

Note that this classifies a start time of exactly noon as afternoon and exactly midnight as morning.

Comment: I'm viewing both dt2 and dt, neither exclusively have mornings or afternoons, where am I suppose to have these data frames that are separated